# Why loadmore button is dissapearing aftre click instead of showing posts?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

[Here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html#comment-1506) I've found a tutorial how to make the load more button with ajax for woocommerce. I copy almost all, except of styles.

Step 1. Load more button

```
global $wp_query; // you can remove this line if everything works for you
 
// don't display the button if there are not enough posts
if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
    echo '<div class="misha_loadmore">More posts</div>'; // you can use <a> as well
```

My variant with a hook looks like that

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop','cosmetic_load_more',9);
function cosmetic_load_more(){?>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center loadmore-wrapper">
        <?php
    global $wp_query; // you can remove this line if everything works for you
     
    // don't display the button if there are not enough posts
    if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
      echo '<button class="loadmore misha_loadmore">See more</button>'; // you can use <a> as well
    ?>
    
  </div>
<?php }
```

Step 2. Enqueue jQuery and myloadmore.js. Pass query parameters to the script

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
 
    global $wp_query; 
 
    // In most cases it is already included on the page and this line can be removed
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
    // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );
 
    // now the most interesting part
    // we have to pass parameters to myloadmore.js script but we can get the parameters values only in PHP
    // you can define variables directly in your HTML but I decided that the most proper way is wp_localize_script()
    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );
```

Step 3. myloadmore.js – what is inside?

```
jQuery(function($){ // use jQuery code inside this to avoid "$ is not defined" error
    $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){
 
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
 
        $.ajax({ // you can also use $.post here
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;
 
                    if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
 
                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Step 4. wp_ajax_

```
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
 
    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
 
    // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
    query_posts( $args );
 
    if( have_posts() ) :
 
        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
 
            // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
            // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
            // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
            // the_title();
 
 
        endwhile;
 
    endif;
    die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}
 
 
 
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

Does it for for you? Where can I be wrong?

Comment: "misha_" word suggests that you have taken the content from https://rudrastyh.com. His posts are normally clean and accurate. If you have made any changes, check those changes again, everything will be fixed.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  `What is not working?` please be specific.  Are you getting errors?  What kind of errors?  Is this an ajax issue, or php issue?  Aside from posting a code tutorial from someone else's website, what is your expected result, and what are you seeing?  Do you have a file called `get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );`

Comment: in console after click I see that error `POST https://i83862.hostua5.fornex.host/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400`.  No, I don't have `get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );` , I have to replace it with woocommerce content product template?